# android retrofit with dynamic variable name and ":" mark

Tags: android, json, variables, dynamic, retrofit

I am getting some data from an api and one of the fields is like this

```
"data": 
{
  "sign_url:60" = "......."
}
```

Also the '60' can take multiple values.How should i name my variable to get that field?

Comment: Okay, so Gson supports field annotations for parsing, but if the 60 is dynamic, I don't think you actually can parse this other than manually looping over the keys of the JSON

Comment: @cricket_007 the '60' is dynamic but it can take only 6 different values , would it be good programming to add 6 variables with all the possible names and just get the not-null one ?

Comment: That should only be done if you don't have a way to fix the source of the data to be more consistent